# Populate changes directly to elastic search

Tags: java, elasticsearch, jhipster

I'm writing a small demo application and used jHipster to generate the stack. As i'm quite new to web development I ran into some issues, especially with elastic search.

Whenever I change entity data in my application, the changed data is not reflected in searches executed using elastic search.

My understanding was that if entity changes were saved in the respective search repository, it should be reflected in the ES indices. Am I mistaken about that?

A live example:

```
@Override
public Client save(Client client) {
    log.debug("Request to save Client : {}", client);
    Client result = clientRepository.save(client);
    clientSearchRepository.save(result);
    return result;
}
```

This stored updated information in my MySQL database, so far so good. However, let's say i edited the birth date of the user and saved it. Whenever I search something containing that client, the "old" birth date still shows up until I perform a reindexation of the ES repositories.

Is it possible to use some kind of entity listener (or anything else) that populates the changed data directly?

Thanks for any pointers.

Answer (score 0):

You should use same searchrepository on your update method. Your code above looks good, if your ElasticSearch config is correct it should update index on create/update of entity.

Use JHipster entity generator and enable elasticsearch and it should work out of the box.

You'll get something like this in your ClientResource for creating new clients:

```
@PostMapping("/clients")
@Timed
public ResponseEntity<Client> createClient(@Valid @RequestBody Client client) throws URISyntaxException {

    Client result = clientRepository.save(client);
    clientSearchRepository.save(result);
```

And something like this for editing your clients:

```
    @PutMapping("/clients")
    @Timed
    public ResponseEntity<Client> updateClient(@Valid @RequestBody Client client) throws URISyntaxException {

    Client result = clientRepository.save(client);
    clientSearchRepository.save(result);
```

Try generating new empty JHipster project and include ElasticSearch ad you'll see that it works like you suppose in the first place.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This is exactly what I would expect it to look like, and jHipster calls the repository directly. 

However, whenever I change some data for e.g Client, the changed information will now show up in search results unless I perform an ES reindexation.

Comment: What part of Client data are you changing. If you are changing data in DB directly ES is not aware of that change and sure, you'll need to reindex it. Change on data need to be propagated through your app, first to DB and then to ES like JHipster generated app does it. In every way, you can schedule the ES reindexing if you are not allowed to modify all applications that write to your DB and can't be modified to call ES.

Comment: I'm changing it through the application, not on the DB directly. This is why I don't understand why populating is not working. My understanding was that the call to clientSearchRepository.save(result); should take care of that.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly it. That's why I said to try and generate new application and see that it works that way. clientSearchRepository extends ElasticsearchRepository, and it's mission is to keep ElasticSearch index in line with database changes. Therefor you have clientSearchRepository methods right after clientRepository in any create/update function of your backend app.